# How to count points intersecting with the end of a multilinestring?

Tags: postgresql, sql, st-intersects

I need to count points from `table1` that intersect with the lines in `table2` which has about an equal split between linestrings and multilinestrings.

Intersect works fine, but the thing is that I need to differentiate between points that intersect in the middle of the line and in the ends (or starts) of the lines.

To do this, I have created the query:

```
 select id,
( SELECT count(*) FROM table2 b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom), b.geom)) AS total_intersected_points,
 ( SELECT count(*) filter (where st_intersects(st_endpoint(a.geom), b.geom ) or st_intersects(st_startpoint(a.geom), b.geom ) ) 
       FROM table2 b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom), b.geom)) AS intersected_startpoints,
 ( SELECT count(*) filter (where not st_intersects(st_endpoint(a.geom), b.geom ) AND NOT st_intersects(st_startpoint(a.geom), b.geom ) ) 
       FROM table2 b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)) AS intersected_midpoints
 from table1 a
```

This works absolutely fine for linestrings, but for multilinestring geometries while I get the accurate count for the first count column, it just returns a zero for the 2nd and 3rd count columns.

Going through the documentation, it seems that `st_endpoint` and `startpoint` used to work on multilinestrings but no longer do so for some reason. There is no way I can separate `table1` into full linestring because I need to use the full geometry which often branches out or has separated segments.

Is there still a way to tackle this and count all the ends of multilinestrings?

Comment: Global starting or ending points for *MultiLinestring*s cannot be well defined geometrically - they are, if at all, subject to interpretation. Since branching means some terminating nodes of individual *Linestring*s may be equal to the edge of others, dumping to its components will not work 100%. You could try to create a concave hull and get intersections with it's boundary.